# Under what circumstances can getnameinfo() return EAI_AGAIN?

Tags: c, linux, dns, glibc

On Glibc/Linux, what can cause `getnameinfo` to return EAI_AGAIN?

Reading the [source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/inet/getnameinfo.c#L243) it seems that EAI_AGAIN can only happen if the internal function `__gethostbyaddr_r` also returns the error code `TRY_AGAIN`.  However, I can't find the definition of that function, so it's difficult to know what can cause it.

In my testing, I found that no error will ever happen unless the `NI_NAMEREQD` flag is set on the `getnameinfo` call, and once that flag is set, I could only cause the return code `-2` (`EAI_NONAME`).

This error, `EAI_NONAME`, occurs in the following conditions:

1. DNS server is reachable, but no name was found for the IP.
2. DNS server is reachable, but the call timed out (tested by creating a fake DNS server that just hangs when answering a query).
3. DNS server defined in /etc/resolv.conf was not connectable.
4. DNS server immediately returned `SERVFAIL` response code.

I expected one of these conditions to trigger the `EAI_AGAIN` response, but no luck.

I am asking this in order to test the behaviour of a program when this condition occurs, but also our of curiosity, having seen it happen sporadically "in the wild", but having been unable to reproduce it.

The testing environment is Linux 4.8.0, Glibc 2.24.

Comment: Basically, whenever underlying interface returns NSS_STATUS_TRYAGAIN; Which according to [NSS Interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/NSS-Modules-Interface.html), can occur when EAGAIN or ERANGE is set; One such occurrence is when server's buffer (allocated from its stack using alloca) is too small to accommodate the response;

Comment: I believe, it is impossible until you use non-blocking sockets.

Comment: Indeed the answer seems to be in the file `resolv/nss_dns/dns-host.c` in the Glibc source tree.  I was hard pressed to figure out exactly what can cause it, though.  Most occurrences of the `NSS_STATUS_TRYAGAIN` macro were in cases of insufficient buffer space, along with a few others that seemed to depend on characteristics of the DNS response.